# Mark a member function as const when it is conceptually not

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

As far as I read here and there, `const` should be used when possible. However, I have a case that always bothers me.

Should I mark a member function as `const` when it does not alter any member variable values but it is not conceptually a `const` function?

For example:

```
class Engine{
public:
    int status;
};

class Car{
public:
   void start() const{
        engine_->status = 1;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Engine> engine_;
};
```

The compiler will accept the **constness** of `start()` since `engine_` as a pointer did not change. However, It seems so unrealistic, at least IMO, that a function called `start` in a class called `Car` is a `const` one!

The example was just a quick one. Usually, some internal states of the `Car` class should be updated accordingly making `const` keyword non-feasible. However, the mini example was just to illustrate my idea.

Comment: The STL uses the convention that calling `const` member functions is thread-safe. Your `start` is not. If you should follow that convention is debatable.

Comment: I recall reading Scott Myers discussing the difference between what he deemed logical const-ness and physical const-ness. That was about introducing `mutable` members (such as a mutex). His point was about justifying the modifiable member, because the logical state of the object remained unchanged, so the member function was justifiably const. I think similar reasoning applies here. The logical state changes, so omitting const may be justifiable.

Comment: Callers usually expect the `const` to refer to the logical state of the object and not it's representation. So it's best to not mark such cases as const. Conversely, member variables that do not express the logical state (such as caching mechanisms) are commonly declared `mutable` to allow for functions to be `const` even though the do alter the representation of the object.

Comment: It's probably worthwhile to mention the Principle of Least Astonishment here -- in this case, if it would surprise the user of your class to find that the start() method is marked const, then that's a good argument for not marking the method const.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case compiler allows you to make `start()` const due to imperfect propagation of constness through pointers. If you replace your pointer with object of type `Engine` your question will disappear. So answer is no, it should not be `const` in this case as using `Engine` as a smart pointer or instance is internal details and should not affect public interface of class `Car`.

> As far as I read here and there, const should be used when possible.

This statement is way too generic, and as with any generic suggestion should not be used formally in every case.

Answer (score 15):

One simple metric for whether a function should be `const` is this:

```
Type a{...};
Type b{...};

bool comp1 = a == b;

b.some_func(...);

bool comp2 = a == b;
```

If `comp1` and `comp2` can *ever* be different, then `some_func` is not `const`.

Obviously, not every type has an `operator==` overload, but most have at least the conceptual idea of what you would test to see if they're equal. Different `Car` instances with different `engine` states would be unequal. Therefore, a function that changes the `engine` state is not `const`.

Comment: Suppose `Type` is a `int&`.  Then your code (replacing `some_func` with a mutating operation on the underlying `int`) can fail.  Reference semantic types (views) can be `const` even if the operation modifies the underying referred-to object, and `==` may compare the underlying objects and not the identity the the reference refers to.  Or, in short `std::reference_wrapper<T>`.

Comment: @Yakk which member of `std::reference_wrapper<T>` marked `const` modifies the underying referred-to object?

Comment: @xskxzr `get()` returns a `T&` and is `const`.  Same with `operator T&()`

Answer (score 4):

In your example, you might want [std::experimental::propagate_const](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const):

```
class Car{
public:
   void start() { engine_->status = 1; }
private:
    std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<Engine>> engine_;
};
```

Then your `start` can no longer be `const`.

Comment: Although it is not the core the problem that I am asking about, I really thank you for mentioning it! I was always wondering why there is no such thing.

Comment: Once `const`is propagated correctly, I have difficulty to see case of `const` methods which is conceptually not. With globals (of any kinds as static member or external file), but then I would say that your concern about constness would be surpassed by that design (issue).

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of `const` can vary.

- Something is `const` if it preserves `==`.
- Something is `const` if your type follows reference semantics and it doesn't change what is referred to.
- Something is `const` if it can be used on any rvalue or lvalue in sensible ways.
- Something is `const` if it is safe to use from multiple threads.
- Something is `const` if it compiles as `const`.
- Something is `const` if whatever state the object claims is internal is not mutated by it.

All of these are reasonable rules to decide if a method or argument is or is not `const`.

A thing to be extremely careful of is to know the difference between `T const*` and `T*const`, and don't accidentally hse top-level const as an internal const.  It isn;t `const iterator` it is `const_iterator`.  It isn't `const gsl::span<int>`, it is `gsl::span<const int>`.  It isn't `const unique_ptr<T>`, it is `unique_ptr<T const>`.

On the other hand, `vector` is a value semantics typr; it pretends its buffer is a part of it (even though this is a lie).  It isn't `vector<const T>`, it is `const vector<T>`.